# Send message to group in Linux

Tags: linux, shell

I found the way to send message to currently logged in user by username:

```
who | grep username | cut -c1-20 | while read line; do  printf  "Message Text" | write $line ; done
```

However, is there anyway I can send message to currently logged in user by group?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The command `groups $line` will return the list of groups that the user belongs to. You can check if the group you want is in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So...  To send a message to every logged in user in a particular group, on every tty they're logged in to...

```
#!/bin/sh

usage() {
  cat <<-EOT
        Usage: writegroup groupname [message]

        where [message] will be taken from stdin if not provided on the command line.
EOT
}

if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
  usage
  exit 1
fi

groupname="$1"
shift
message="$*"

if [ -z "$message" ]; then
  read message
fi

who | while read user tty junk; do
  if groups "$user" | grep -wq "$groupname"; then
    echo "$message" | write "$user" "$tty"
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Provided you set the variable `group` to the group you're interested in, you can try this:

```
for i in $(who -u | cut -d " " -f1 | sort | uniq); do if  echo $(groups $i | cut -d " " -f3-) | grep $group >/dev/null; then echo "Message Text" | write $i; fi; done
```

`$(who -u | cut -d " " -f1 | sort | uniq)` gives the list of user logged in.

`$(groups $i | cut -d " " -f3-)` gives all groups a user belongs to.

The `grep` statement will reduce the list to the user belonging to the `$group`

Comment: In /etc/group, the content is like group:x:111. and in etc/group-, the content is like username:x:111. Cannot find group.username thus no message was sent using your script. Please help.

Comment: On my ubuntu the `/etc/group` is in the format `sudo:x:27:user1,user2`. Is it the same on your system? If not, please give an example line containing at least 2 users of that file.

Comment: Also, best to use the `groups` command rahter than parsing system files which may differ from OS to OS or even distro to distro.

Comment: thanks for the tip, i edited my answer using the `groups` command

Comment: Using groups works! However, this script does not send on every tty they're logged in.